# javascript event.keyCode doesn't work on keydown, keypress or keyup events in FireFox 3.6.25

Tags: javascript, event-handling, keyboard

Please someone help a very desperate and weary novice.  I have searched everywhere for an answer but to no avail.

I want to capture the keyCode/charCode to test whether the enter key has been pressed (I have been using keydown but I'm not fussed as long as I get something working).  I have tried every conceivable solution and it works fine in IE, Safari, Chrome and Opera but NOT IN FireFox 3.6.25 (the latest)?! I know the event is definitely triggering as I can display a simple alert box from the function I call, but as for declaring a variable to hold the contents of event.keyCode, that's another matter entirely!

The code of my form is basically...

```
<form method="post" name="giftaidform" onsubmit="javascript:return validateForm();" action="../scripts/form-to-email.php">
<table width="500" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="180" align="right">Forename:</td>
    <td align="left"><input name="forename" type="text" size="30" maxlength="30" onfocus="javascript:setUnchecked(this);" onkeydown="javascript:testForEnter(this);" onblur="javascript:isValidName(this);"></td>
  </tr>
```

and so on...

As for my "testForEnter" function...

```
function testForEnter(obj) {
// store code of key that was pressed
var keyCode = obj.keyCode;
alert(keyCode);
// if the enter key was pressed then prevent default action
if (keyCode == 13) {
    if(event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
    event.returnValue = false;
}
 }
```

I have tried various other formulations including obj.charCode and stuff like below?!

```
function checkKey(evt) {
  var keyID = (window.event) ? window.event.keyCode : event.which;
  alert(keyID);
}
```

Nothing works in FireFox!

Comment: Nothing works because you named the parameter `evt` and not `event`. In your code, `window.event` and `event` are both referring to `window.event`, which does not exist in Firefox. You should normalize the event first, using `var event = window.event || event;`. And the latest Firefox is `9`, not `3.6`. Also note that when you call a function from your inline event handler, you have to pass the `event` object to it if you want to access it.

Comment: You don't need that "javascript:" at the beginning of your "onfoo" handler strings.

Comment: @FelixKling you are a legend!  I have now passed 'event' and sorted out my dodgy code and its working perfectly - not to mention having upgraded to version 9 of firefox (no idea how i managed to install an old version)!

Comment: @Pointy - thank you! i can now simplify my html!

Comment: I provided my comment as answer, so that you can accept it (click the tick outline next to it). I also corrected a mistake in my comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing works because you named the parameter `evt` and not `event`. In your code, `window.event` and `event` are both referring to `window.event`, which does not exist in Firefox.

You should normalize the event first, for example using

```
var event = evt || window.event;
```

or rename the parameter from `evt` to `event` (and then drop the `var` above).

Also note that when you call a function from your inline event handler, you have to pass the event object to it if you want to access it.

Comment: Just a quick related question if you know the answer (and can indulge my ignorance for a moment longer). returnValue and preventDefault do stop the default action on Enter keypress in all browsers except FF. I read that adding stopPropagation will work for FF but have added it as well as cancelBubble but it doesn't seem to stop the form validation function from running. Any ideas? :S

Comment: Calling `event.stopPropagation()` should indeed work. Make sure the `event` object is available in your `testForEnter` function, currently it is not. I also recommend to install Firebug for debugging your code. You will see on the console when your code throws an error.

Answer (score 3):

This is the code that I now have and it is fully operational in all five main browsers:

I now call the functions as follows:

```
<input name="forename" type="text" size="30" maxlength="30" onkeydown="testForEnter(this,event);" onblur="isValidName(this);">
```

My function is as follows:

```
// testForEnter() disables the enter keypress on all form objects except for submit button
// this function works in IE, chrome, safari, opera and firefox
function testForEnter(obj,evt) {
    var keyCode = evt.keyCode;
    var objType = obj.type;
    if ((keyCode == 13) && (objType != "submit")) {
        evt.returnValue = false;
        evt.stopPropagation(); // this line added for firefox
        if(evt.preventDefault) evt.preventDefault();
}
} //end of testForEnter()
```

Hope this helps somebody else!

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
var keycode = evt.charCode;
```

It seems to work in both browsers.